# Is there a list of contract addresses for WETH?

Tags: addresses

Is there a list of contract addresses for WETH?

I am looking for the contract address for Sepolia in particular, and I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to note that there are no "official" WETH, USDT, or USDC on testnets. You can deploy your own WETH contract on Sepolia for testing if needed.

However, you can still interact with different protocols that have their versions of WETH.

For example, Aave has a WETH contract on Sepolia, which you can find here: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xd0df82de051244f04bff3a8bb1f62e1cd39eed92

As for Uniswap, I checked and haven't found any support for Sepolia yet, but they might soon and likely have their own version of WETH as well.

Answer (score 1):

> As for Uniswap, I checked and haven't found any support for Sepolia yet, but they might soon and likely have their own version of WETH as well.

Uniswap just deployed a WETH contract with the same bytecode as mainnet here: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xfff9976782d46cc05630d1f6ebab18b2324d6b14#code

Here it is listed on the Uniswap default token list for verification: https://github.com/Uniswap/default-token-list/blob/main/src/tokens/sepolia.json#L4

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! A user flagged suggesting disclosing your affiliation to Uniswap.